# Pandas : add a prefix to data following a certain position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I try to add a prefix in front of "Label" type data under certain conditions.

Example of my actual data :

```
          Label            Word
9             O                
10       PERSON               J 
11       PERSON          Chirac
12            O             Les
13            O        archives
14            O   électroniques
15            O              et
16            O  audiovisuelles
17            O        décrites
18            O             ici
19            O         émanent
20            O             des
21            O        services
22            O       rattachés
23            O              au
24            O                
25  INSTITUTION         Cabinet
26  INSTITUTION              du
27  INSTITUTION       président
28  INSTITUTION              de
29  INSTITUTION              la
30  INSTITUTION      République
...
```

I would like to ignore the label "O" however if a first label is encountered add a "B-" in front of the label and the following labels with an "I-", as follows:

expected output :

```
          Label            Word
9             O                
10     B-PERSON               J 
11     I-PERSON          Chirac
12            O             Les
13            O        archives
14            O   électroniques
15            O              et
16            O  audiovisuelles
17            O        décrites
18            O             ici
19            O         émanent
20            O             des
21            O        services
22            O       rattachés
23            O              au
24            O                
25 B-INSTITUTION         Cabinet
26 I-INSTITUTION              du
27 I-INSTITUTION       président
28 I-INSTITUTION              de
29 I-INSTITUTION              la
30 I-INSTITUTION      République
...
```

I started by applying the prefix "B-" as follows :

```
def change(label):
    if label != 'O': 
        return f'B-{label}'
    else: 
        return label

df['Label'] = df['Label'].apply(lambda x: change(x))
```

which gives this :

```
            Label            Word
9               O                
10       B-PERSON               J 
11       B-PERSON          Chirac
12              O             Les
13              O        archives
14              O   électroniques
15              O              et
16              O  audiovisuelles
17              O        décrites
18              O             ici
19              O         émanent
20              O             des
21              O        services
22              O       rattachés
23              O              au
24              O                
25  B-INSTITUTION         Cabinet
26  B-INSTITUTION              du
27  B-INSTITUTION       président
28  B-INSTITUTION              de
29  B-INSTITUTION              la
30  B-INSTITUTION      République
```

and then to add a prefix "I-" following the previous or next value by the biai of the `.shift()` method.

with code as follows (does not work):

```
df['Label'].apply(lambda x: f'I-{x}' if ((f"B-{x}" in df['Label'].shift(-1)) and ("O" in df['Label'].shift(1)) else x)
```

However, all this seems too complicated for this task and not necessarily functional, does anyone have a different lead to consider?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create two boolean masks where the first boolean mask `m1` represent the condition where `Label` is not equal to `O` while the other boolean mask `m2` represent the condition where `Label` is not equal `O` and previous `Label` equals `O`, then use `np.select` with these masks to choose from `B-` or `I-` to concat in front of `Label`:

```
m1 = df['Label'].ne('O')
m2 = m1 & df['Label'].shift().eq('O')

df['Label'] = np.select([m2, m1], ['B-', 'I-'], '') + df['Label']
```

---

```
            Label            Word
0               0            None
1        B-PERSON               J
2        I-PERSON          Chirac
3               0             Les
4               0        archives
5               0   électroniques
6               0              et
7               0  audiovisuelles
8               0        décrites
9               0             ici
10              0         émanent
11              0             des
12              0        services
13              0       rattachés
14              0              au
15              0            None
16  B-INSTITUTION         Cabinet
17  I-INSTITUTION              du
18  I-INSTITUTION       président
19  I-INSTITUTION              de
20  I-INSTITUTION              la
21  I-INSTITUTION      République
```

Comment: I just tested. Yes indeed ! this is a faster implementation than my initial idea. thank you

Comment: @LucasTerriel happy coding :)